# get image size using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the image size using javascript or jquery. something similar to imagesize().

Thanks
Jean

Answer (score 2):

Has already been asked and answered - [How to get image size (height & width) using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623172/how-to-get-image-size-height-width-using-javascript)

```
var img = document.getElementById('imageid'); 
var width = img.clientWidth;
var height = img.clientHeight;
```

Answer (score 2):

That depends. If the image already has width/height styles/attributes applied to it, you will not get the image's width/height, but you will get the resized dimensions. Here's a possible solution:

```
function getImageSize(img) {
    var clone = img.clone();
    clone.width("auto")
         .height("auto")
         .css("position", "absolute")
         .css("left", -9999)
         .css("top", -9999);
    $(document.body).append(clone);
    var width = clone.width();
    var height = clone.height();
    clone.remove();
    return [width, height];
}
```

Untested, but it should work. However, if you're sure the image is not resized from css/html, there's no need for this complication and you can use what the others have said.

Answer (score 0):

> var width = $("#img").width();

Answer (score 0):

you can use .attr('width') and .attr('height') unless you mean size in bytes?

this wouldnt work if the img is being rescaled with css